# Validar un input vacio cuando se haga un retroceso o 'backspace' con VueJS2

Tags: html, vue.js, post

En un html tengo un `v-model='code'`con un atributo `v-on:change='consultar()'`el cual al momento de digitar el codigo y tabular (por ejemplo, (es una de muchas formas para hacer el change)), el va a ese metodo y me lista los datos en un formulario, hasta ahi bien!

**'El problema'**

En el metodo `'consultar'` valido que cuando este vacio se limpie el formulario y cuando no que ejecute el post, **el problema es que para validar que el campo este vacio o no, siempre debo de hacer un change** y la idea es que mientras haga el `backspace` y sepa que está vacio me limpie el formulario sin tener que hacer el change.

**Codigo**

*HTML*

```
<input type="text" v-model='code' v-on:change='consultar()' placeholder="ingrese codígo">
```

*VueJS*

```
new Vue({
    el: '#content',
    data: {
        code: '',
        datos: {
            name: '',
            etc..
        } // Aqui van todos los parametros para el formulario
    },
    methods: {
        consultar: function () {
            if (this.code == '') {
                this.datos = {},
            } else {
                // ejecutar el post
            }
        },
    },
})
```

Agradezco el interes.

Comment: vas a hacer backspace sobre un campo que esta vacio?? entonces el evento change no va a ocurrir.. ese es el problema?? busca otro evento ;)

Comment: Hola @gbianchi, que pena quizas no me hice entender, el por defecto ya viene vacio, cuando digito el codigo y hago el change se envia la peticion y la idea es que el input apenas sienta que se hizo un retroceso se limpie el formulario, no se si asi lo comprendes mejor. Un saludo.

Comment: un retroceso de pagina??? vos decis volver a la pagina anterior???

Comment: No men, el input de un formulario esta esperando que yo coloque un codigo que al momento de hacer un change se "pinta" la informacion en los demas campos, cuando yo empieze a borrar el codigo (borrar es como cuando te equivoques y oprimes la tecla backspace la que esta arriba del enter para borrar, esa misma), se limpie el formulario.

Comment: ah ok.. yo no le veo nada de malo a como haces ahora.. pero veamos si alguien mas tiene otra idea. Si no tendrias que ver un keychange o algo asi.. y acordarte que tecla viene apretando.. por eso no le veo sentido...

Comment: ¿Quieres vaciar el input al pulsar una vez la tecla de borrar? Si es así puedes usar el código de la tecla como condición: `event.keyCode === 8`

Answer (score 1):

Existe la posibilidad de colocarle a tu input un evento 'keyup' o 'keydown'. También desde allí puedes especificar con qué tecla se va a activar el evento.

En tu caso para recibir cada vez que se presione el backspace:

```
<input type="text" v-model='code' @keyup.delete='consultar()' placeholder="ingrese codígo">
```

Esto hará que al presionar y soltar la tecla backspace tu método "consultar" será llamado. Si deseas que sea especificamente para keydown (digamos, porque quieres hacer un preventDefault para evitar que se realize la acción de borrar un caracter) puedes hacerlo tambien. La razón por la que se hace esto con keydown y no keyup es porque estas acciones por defecto de la tecla backspace se lleva a cabo al presionar la tecla y no al soltarla. Acá un ejemplo:

```
<input type="text" v-model='code' @keydown.delete='consultar()' placeholder="ingrese codígo">
<input type="text" v-model='code' @keydown.delete.prevent='consultar()' placeholder="ingrese codígo"> //Para preventDefault en vuejs. Ten en cuenta que los event modifiers se stackean de dicha manera. También es lo mismo hacer v-on: que usar @
```

El modifier ".delete" también se activa con la tecla suprimir. Si solo deseas que se active con backspace específicamente entonces debes de definir un Key Code usando Vue.config.keyCodes de la siguiente manera:

```
Vue.config.keyCodes = {
  'backspace': 8 //El key 'backspace' definirá el modifier que le agregaremos a nuestro evento keyup/keydown. El número es el ID de dicho botón
}
```

Ya teniendo nuesto key code definido en nuestra APP Vue, podemos usarlo libremente.

```
<input type="text" v-model='code' @keydown.backspace='consultar()' placeholder="ingrese codígo"> //Ahora solo se activará con backspace!
```

Referencias:

- [Key modifiers (.delete, etc)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Key-Modifiers)
- [Event modifiers (uso de .stop, .prevent, etc)](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers)
- [Definiendo Key codes en Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#keyCodes)
- [Tabla de valores de Key codes e información extra](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/javascript-keycodes/)